# Remove URL parameter from Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site that is using the "post name" permalink settings.

I have also setup a link in my site with a URL variable:

http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/test/?location=London

I would like to modify this URL to just http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/test/London

but it's messing the htaccess up for the rest of the wordpress site

I have tried the following htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
//remove location name
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /test/?location=$1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that I know you can achieve it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "location=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /test/$1? [R=301,L]
```

to make sure the query gets deleted you need to move the code lines bellow RewriteBase / . so it looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "location=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /test/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You can also remove the query using a simplified rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /location? [R,L]
```