# want to hide "?" from url but need the keys from url

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

The URL of my website is http://www.xxxxxx.co.nz/industry/?marine but i want to make it as http://www.xxxxxx.co.nz/industry/marine but marine is a key-value passed after "?".
please give me the solution is it possible to make the URL in such a way that i can pass the key values to the URL without "?" sign.

Comment: Hi. You are using WordPress and the ubermenu plugin. Please share how you create the industry submenu items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove URL parameter from Wordpress URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994401/remove-url-parameter-from-wordpress-url)

Comment: @initall just make different menu segments. there is option on the left "advanced ubermenu options" . add a menu segments named industry. then simply add the subitems into it.

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but according to the docs [Menu Segment](https://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/advanced-menu-items/menu-segment) _Menu segments allow you to inject items from a separate menu into the current menu_. Maybe instead of subitems you have to select another menu?

Comment: yes, @initall i have made different sections of menu.. make a different section and then normally add the subitems in it.

Comment: Ok, are, for example "Chemical" and "Marine" pages? And are they part of an individual menu, e.g. a "Industry Menu" - so that you can add the Industry Menu (with it's page navigation items) as a segment to be inserted?

Comment: yes yes exactly,same thing..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via .htaccess see below code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

after this using prams in php

```
<?php

$params = explode( "/", $_GET['params'] );
for($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i+=2) {

  echo $params[$i] ." has value: ". $params[$i+1] ."<br />";

}

?>
```

so your url should be like this

```
http://yourURL.com/key/value
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but my page is not static,i can't use .htaccess. This page is dynamic like..  http://www.customcontrols.co.nz/industry/?marine http://www.customcontrols.co.nz/industry/?chemical http://www.customcontrols.co.nz/industry/?food etc. these all are the slugs from which i get the category id which is used for development of pages

Comment: @TejbirKaur - that is precisely why you CAN use a `.htaccess` file in situations like this. There appear to be many rewrite rules used elsewhere on the site

Comment: You can use SPA (Single Page Application) approach and load you dynamic pages in a single page according  to the arguments recive